# SpringSecurityUser class not found in Maven repository

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-security

I am following this tutorial: [Java Integration with Amazon Cognito Developer Tutorial](https://gorillalogic.com/blog/java-integration-with-amazon-cognito/). At the part with heading Sign In Implementation. The code found under that heading uses the class SpringSecurityUser. That actually belongs to package org.opennms.web.springframework.security.SpringSecurityUser, but maven repository doesn't have that, so I found another package that seems closest to the one in that code in the tutorial.

I am using Eclipse in macOS Mojave. I got this dependency from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web/3.1.3.RELEASE)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/org.springframework.security.web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.security.web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the error message at the dependency opening tag above:

> Missing artifact 
>    org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:jar:
>    3.1.3.RELEASE

Here is my import statement:

```
import org.springframework.security.web;
```

This is the error message I get:

> The import org.springframework cannot be 
>    resolved

I don't know what to check to resolve this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try updating your project using right click on the project --> Maven --> Update Project.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Yes. I've tried that. It didn't fix the problem. Thank you for your effort to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpringSecurityUser` is from `OpenMNS` which can be found from :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.opennms.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.opennms.features.springframework-security</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But it is not available from the central maven repository. You have to add `OpenMNS` maven repository in `pom.xml` in order to download it :

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>opennms-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.opennms.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>     
  </repositories>
```

Comment: Do I need to also set the <dependencyManagement>?

Comment: How did you find that information? I have another class that I can't find the repository for.

Comment: Base on the package name of  `SpringSecurityUser`, I go to  `opennms` Guthub and search that it is located in [this repo](https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/tree/develop/features/springframework-security) .Check its [pom.xml](https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/blob/45d9f0ade5534b96a324c474ab315a05a2b2be1d/features/springframework-security/pom.xml#L9) can confirm its `groupId` and `artifactId` . Then go to this [web site](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opennms.features/org.opennms.features.springframework-security/24.1.0)  to search it and find that it is only available in Openmns repo

Comment: I search in openmns github and not aware it provides something related to  `<dependencyManagement>`  feature that we can use it , so you do not need to set `<dependencyManagement>` for the artifactId come from openmns